# Strange behavior in FFT window

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm having some strange behavior in my windowing of a FFT of two signals. One is a standard 145hz driving signal, the other is a bouncing ball. After applying the windowing, I'm getting some clear peaks as expected, but in between them are strange groups of smaller peaks (usually 4) rather than a single resolved peak. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code

```
d = A(:,1);   % Driving Signal
y = A(:,2);   % Bouncing Ball

d = d(1:16:2^16); 
y = y(1:16:2^16);

fSamp = 44100/16; 

Pdd = (abs(fft(d))).^2; 
Pyy = (abs(fft(y))).^2; 
N = length(Pyy);
n = 1:N;n = n';
nn = 1:N
hanning = 0.5*(1-cos(2*n*pi/(N-1)));
window = hanning;
zw = y.*window;
Pzw = (abs(fft(zw))).^2;
stop = length(Pyy)/2; 
Pdd = Pdd(1:stop);
Pyy = Pyy(1:stop);
Pzw = Pzw(1:stop);
nd = 1:stop;
fdd = nd*(fSamp/2)/stop; 
semilogy(fdd,Pdd,fdd,Pyy,fdd,Pzw)
title('Unwindowed/Windowed')
xlabel('frequency (Hz)')
```

[image]

I've tried different sampling frequencies, however nothing seems to change the output.

Comment: Try drawing `1:stop` indices of `abs(fft(window)).^2` together with other lines. What do you see?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, Isn't what I'm doing with `Pzw = Pzw(1:stop);`?

Comment: See the frequency response of the window itself, not only the windowed signal.